# Row with half equal section containing same image overlapped HTML

Tags: html, css, row, overlapping

I really want to know how to achieve this kind of structure using HTML CSS including media queries. See image below:[image]

On smaller screens section 1 will be on top overlapping little portion of the picture contained by section 2.
You must see the picture above to understand my question. The main problem is I really want to do something like this but I don't know where start. I don't want to break any CSS structure using negative margins and padding.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: @IlGala I haven't tried anything. Just give me a hint in writing I'll definitely come up with the code. I already mentioned that I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? Resize the browser window (make it smaller) to see the effect.

HTML:

```
<div id="section1">
    &nbsp;
</div>

<div id="section2">
    <div id="overlay">
        Overlay
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#section1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: grey;
}

#section2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: -20px;
    background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #section1, #section2 {
        float: none;
    }
    #overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: 90px;
        background: red;
    }
 }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrym5ged/)